# How I can capture values in command line and add to recipe?

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

I am new to Chef and Ruby

I need to pass two variables to Chef on the command line and have those variables available in a recipe.

How I can capture these values and get them in Chef?

I need something like this:

```
before_deploy command 
  execute param1 param2
deploy{ param1/param2}
```

Where `param1` and `param2` get their values at run-time from the command-line.

Comment: I need anything like this before_deploy command execute param1: getparam1, param2: getparam2. deploy{ http://param1/param2} I don´t know how I get these params from command line

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you provision the machine by running

```
chef-solo
```

or

```
chef-client
```

you cannot provide any arguments to these commands that can be visible to recipes. Chef recipes work only with [attributes](http://wiki.opscode.com/display/chef/Attributes). Good thing (or not so good) is that attributes can be set from many different places: roles, nodes, environments and json file.

The workaround that is nearest to your request is

- Create a json-file on the machine
- Pass it when running `chef-client` or `chef-solo`
- Use attributes in the recipe

For example: apache config.

create json file: my_attrs.json

```
{ 
  "apache": {
    "listen_port": "81",
    "listen_path": "/myapp"
  }
}
```

and then use them in your recipe:

```
node[:apache][:listen_port]
node[:apache][:listen_path]
```

Run `chef-client` or `chef-solo` with `-j` flag.

```
chef-solo -j my_attrs.json
```

If my_attrs.json is on some remote server, then you can provide a url.

```
chef-solo -j http://remote.host/path/my_attrs.json
```

Answer (score 0):

If your file is named example.rb

```
ruby example.rb argument1 argument2
```

Then

```
ARGV.each do|a|
  puts "Argument: #{a}"
end
```

Output:

```
Argument: argument1
Argument: argument2
```

Comment: This is actually a possible answer, i don't understand why people have downvoted this without a reason. +1 from my side.

Answer (score 0):

You can set variables inside recipes by calling commands

```
nodename = `cat /etc/chef/client.rb | grep "node_name" | sed -e 's/\<node_name\>//g' | sed '/^$/d;s/[[:blank:]]//g' | sed 's/\"//g'`
```

And then use the variable for other chef blocks

```
execute "echo nodename for node #{nodename}"
 command "echo #{nodename}"
 action :run
 only_if {nodename == "node1"}
end
```

This will get the node.name attribute from the client.rb file without asking for it to the chef server.