# Chef and ruby how to to load a text file into a hash

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

I have a tab delimited file called text.txt. as follows.

```
a\tb
c\td
```

I a chef run I need to load that file into a hash called myhash.

How do I do that?

Comment: Nothing.  I dont know how to open a file in ruby like I can in python.  I use chef but a am a python developer

Comment: Ruby File documentation: http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/File.html

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14730833/how-i-can-capture-values-in-command-line-and-add-to-recipe

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about chef, but here is a pure ruby solution. Maybe it helps:

```
file = File.open('test.txt', 'r')
lines = file.readlines
file.close
myhash = Hash.new
lines.each do |line|
  line.chomp!
  key, value = line.split("\t")
  myhash[key] = value
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to reformat your test file into json:

```
{
   "a": "b",
   "c": "d"
}
```

And then you can run `chef-client` or `chef-solo` providing this json file:

```
chef-solo -j myfile.json
```

You will be able to use these data as node attributes in recipes like that:

```
node[:a] #equals "b"
node[:c] #equals "d"
```