# Use knife to bootstrap recipe on server and forward version parameter

Tags: chef-infra, knife

I have a very short recipe that looks something like this:

```
bash "install app" do
    cwd "/var/lib/app"
    code <<-EOH
    npm set registry http://npm.app.com/
    npm install app
    EOH
end
```

And I run the following knife command:

```
knife bootstrap 1.2.3.4 --ssh-user root --ssh-password password --ssh-port 22 --run-list "recipe[myapp]"
```

I would like to know how to pass on a version number in my knife command and change the bash script to also take that version, something like this:

```
knife bootstrap 1.2.3.4 --ssh-user root --ssh-password password --ssh-port 22 --run-list "recipe[myapp]" --ver 2.2.30
```

And the recipe should look like this:

```
bash "install app" do
    cwd "/var/lib/app"
    code <<-EOH
    npm set registry http://npm.app.com/
    npm install app@2.2.30
    EOH
end
```

I read on the knife bootstrap manual that I can use the '-j' flag to pass json parameters but I can't find any examples on how to actually use these json parameters within the recipe..

Comment: Check out answer to http://stackoverflow.com/q/14730833/170230

Answer (score 0):

Yeah .. u can pass the parameter at run time . as you wanted a version to be seen

node.default['version'] = node['version'].to_hash
node.default['version'].each do |version, version_value|

```
bash "install app" do 
     cwd "/var/lib/app" 
     code <<-EOH  
       npm set registry http://npm.app.com/  
       npm install app@<@ = version_value>   
   EOH  
end
```

command for bootstrapping:

knife bootstrap 1.2.3.4 -x root -P password -r "recipe[myapp]" -j '{"version":{"version_value":"2.2.30"}}'