# Chef Solo get user input

Tags: chef-infra, chef-solo

I don't know why I can't find anything on the interwebs about this.

I basically want to write a recipe that prompts a user for their github username/password, then posts to the github API to add an ssh key.

I'm sure I can prompt a user with normal ruby methods (ie gets) but this doesn't seem natural given all the utilities chef provides.

Can someone tell me a 'chef' way of prompting a user for input to store in vars for later use?

I'd like to first output some instructions for the user to read, then get the username, then password, I guess for safety reasons, the password should not be shown on the console as they type

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem? It's okay to answer your own question. Please don't forget to mark an answer as correct! :)

Comment: This might answer your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14730833/how-i-can-capture-values-in-command-line-and-add-to-recipe

Answer (score 4):

I'd say chef is not made for such user input.

You might use ruby code that is executed during the compile phase of the chef run, but I'd suggest the following:

*What about reading it from an [environment variable](http://docs.opscode.com/essentials_environment_variables.html)?*

Comment: so I guess it's not standard behaviour then...  My problem is that my chef script is itself run from an automated script, so it'd be kind of annoying to set ENV vars before that

Answer (score 1):

It feels super dirty, but this actually works. Maybe some things can be tuned so that it feels a bit more clean:

```rb
file "/tmp/ans" do
  puts "Enter something useful!"
  content ::STDIN.readline
end
```

You can apply such a recipe with `chef-apply`, note that using [Vagrant](http://www.vagrantup.com) will not work.

Still, I would recommend do it differently. Another way would be to not call chef directly, but through a wrapper script. This could read the data from the user and write it into a json file, which is then given to chef via the `-j PATH, --json-attributes PATH` parameter (see [chef-solo parameters](http://docs.opscode.com/ctl_chef_solo.html)).

Comment: Oh.. or that script could set the environment variables :D (but the using the `-j` parameters feels cleaner.

Comment: interesting idea...  I'll give it a shot and get back to you, thx!

Comment: If you have to ask this question you probably shouldn't use this answer.  If you know about user inputs and ptys and could write your own `expect(1)` you should feel free to do this.  If you can't, and you run into trouble with this approach, and expect to submit bugs to chef-client wanting help with it, we'll probably tell you that you need to use an ENV var and a wrapper script that calls something more appropriate for user input, and we won't be able to teach you how to fix all the bugs in your ruby script.  You will be stuck in the mud and we won't be able to pull you out.

Comment: Have you been stuck in the mud for 7 years until being able to answer? :D Just kidding ;)