# Prompt during Chef provision

Tags: vagrant, chef-infra, perforce

Part of a Chef cookbook I'm writing is configuring perforce, which requires the user to enter their password (lest they save this in plaintext in an "attributes" file). Is it possible to interrupt the provisioning with an interactive prompt?

Comment: This is a terrible idea. Chef is meant to be an unattended thing... How would this ever run as a service?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Chef Solo get user input](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19754127/chef-solo-get-user-input)

Comment: The whole project is supposed to set up a dev environment, which includes syncing some necessary files from a perforce repo. The other option here is to have users do that step manually - would that be better practice?

Comment: Why do you need a prompt for that?

Comment: I just need some way for the user to provide their password. Is there a better way?

Comment: You should either 1.) Read if from the environment 2.) Use key-based authentication.

Comment: Seth is right, in general those are your 2 options. I'm sure there is some sort of weird workaround but... That said, you may be interested in chef-shell or shef: http://docs.getchef.com/chef_shell.html

Answer (score 4):

We would prompt the user from the Vagrantfile and then set that value as a Chef attribute. Prompts really only makes sense on dev boxes, so they really shouldn't be part of the Chef recipe:

```
Vagrant.configure('2') do |config|
  config.vm.provision :chef_client do |chef|
    chef.add_role 'dev'
    chef.chef_server_url = 'https://api.opscode.com/organizations/myorg'
    chef.node_name = "vagrant-#{ENV['USER']}-dev.example.com"
    chef.validation_key_path = 'example-validator'
    chef.json = {
      'mysvc' => {
        'password' => MySvc.password()
      }
    }
  end
end

module MySvc
  def self.password
    begin
      system 'stty -echo'
      print 'MySvc Password: '
      ; pass = $stdin.gets.chomp; puts "\n"
    ensure
      system 'stty echo'
    end
    pass
  end
end
```

Comment: This would be exactly what I need - but the final cookbook needs to be applied to non-vagrant VMs. I think I'm just going to go with some hacky solution.

Comment: @giraffe What "hacky solution" did you ultimately go with? I have a similar problem to yours and I'd be interested to know how you solved it, even if your solution was sub-optimal.

Comment: I think I ended up encasing the Chef provision in a Bash script which would ask for a username and password. Those environment variables would be passed into Chef. Can't remember for sure though.

Answer (score 3):

Correct me if i misunderstood your problem, if you want to read user input :
You can use built-in SHELL command "read".

example:

```
[myprompt]$ read -p "Insert text : " IN_TEXT
Insert text : user input
[myprompt]$ echo $IN_TEXT
user input
```

ps: if you use read command for password you can use "-s" option to hide input coming from terminal.

example2 :

```
[myprompt]$ read -sp "Insert text : " IN_TEXT
Insert text :                                            //stdin <<"user input"
[myprompt]$ echo $IN_TEXT
user input
```

Comment: This isn't working with Chef (though I'm currently running it on vagrant)... It just proceeds without waiting for user input (or even printing "Insert text")...

Comment: my code work under bash command line, i think the "bash" tag in your question confused me