# How do I assign a value to a variable inside my chef recipe at runtime

Tags: chef-infra, chef-solo

In scripting languages like shell/perl, I could use variables to get a specific directory name at run time which can be used in the script. But inside a chef recipe how do I make use of variables without passing them as parameters

I want to assign output of a shell command line to a variable- How do I achieve it within a chef recipe. I am using chef-solo.

Shell example:

```
install_dir=`grep install /tmp/my_info.txt | cut -d"/" -f4`
cd /dev/install_dir
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Chef Solo get user input](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19754127/chef-solo-get-user-input)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tested out your recipe? The syntax is already correct. For instance if I have a file `/tmp/my_info.txt` and the contents of said file are something like:

```
install is here
but not here
```

And I run the following Chef recipe:

```
install_dir = `grep install /tmp/my_info.txt`
Chef::Log.error("Result of grep is: #{install_dir}")
```

Then the output from a chef-client run will be:

```
ERROR: Result of grep is: install is here
```

If you need to use install_dir in some resource (which you haven't really shown), it could be something as simple as:

```
directory "#{install_dir}" do
  owner "root"
  group "root"
  mode 00644
  action :create
end
```

Comment: Yes I could make it happen by writing the values to files, and creating another file with formatted value. But it sounds like too much overhead for a variable usage.                                       First I will create the myinfo file as :                                 unzip #{extract_path}/* -d /tmp | grep install.csh | cut -d":" -f2 >  /tmp/my_info.txt    Then I will extract the directory name as   install_dir=`grep install /tmp/my_info.txt | cut -d"/" -f4` 
echo "/dev/#{install_dir}/setup > /dev/install_script_path          grep again to another variable to get the output string

Comment: ??? So I guess I don't understand what your question is, the above works. If it seems silly to do it all via calls like those above, write your own shell script to call from Chef with the `bash` resource

Comment: @DisplayNameismissing You might have missed a lead from the question, indeed. It reads: "How do I assign a value to a variable inside my chef recipe **at runtime**". Variables assigned in chef with the backtick syntax are assigned at *compile time* as opposed to *execution time* (a.k.a. runtime). Therefore, if the data doesn't exist **before** the chef execution, it will fail. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25980820/ for further information.

Comment: @7heo.tk good call - that link helps. But as are many questions on SO... the world will never know until Balualways responds ;)