# I have been asked to make changes to a chef cookbook so that it installs Java only if its required?

Tags: java, chef-recipe

I have a cookbook that installs four packages three of which are custom build packages and one is Java. While using bootstrap, Java is getting installed. I have been asked to remove Java from the cookbook and place in another cookbook and install Java only if its required. Below is the code of the package that will be installed by the cookbook. How to arrive at conclusion if Java is required for a service and then install it?

```
default['******']['packages'] = 
[
  { 'name' => 'java-1.8.0-openjdk', 'version' => '1:1.8.0.101-3.b13.el7_2' },
  { 'name' => '********', 'version' => '11.0.0.0' },
  { 'name' => '********', 'version' => '11.0.0.0' },
  { 'name' => '********', 'version' => '11.0.0.0' }
]
```

Comment: https://docs.chef.io/resource_common.html search: conditional in that page. Also this seems to be a duplicate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Chef conditional resource argument](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29922901/chef-conditional-resource-argument)