# Run arbitrary ruby code in a chef cookbook

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, cookbook, recipe

I have a simple chef cookbook and all it does is it sets the MOTD on a CentOS machine. It takes the content of the /tmp/mymotd.txt and turns it into the MOTD.

I also have a simple ruby script (a full-fledged ruby script) that simply reads the text from the web-server and puts in into the /tmp/mymotd.txt.

My questions are:

1. how do I run this ruby script from within the cookbook?
2. how do I pass some parameters to the script (e.g. the address of the web-server)

Thanks a lot beforehand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Ad 1.**

You can use `libraries` directory in scripts to place there your ruby script and declare it in a module. Example:

```
# includes
module MODULE_NAME
    # here some code using your script 

    # Example function
    def example_function (text)
        # some code
    end
end
```

You can use then

```
include MODULE_NAME
```

in your recipe to import those functions and just use it like

```
example_function(something)
```

What's good - you can use there also Chef functions and resources.

**IMPORTANT INFO:** Just remember that Chef has 2 compilation phases. First will be all of Ruby code, second all of Chef resources. This means, that you have to remember priority of code. I won't write here more info about it, since you haven't asked for this, but if you want, you can find it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25980820/please-explain-compile-time-vs-run-time-in-chef-recipes).

**Ad 2.**

You can do this in several ways, but it seems to me, that the best option for you would be to use `environments`. You can find more info [in here](https://docs.chef.io/environments.html). Basically, you can set up environment for script before it will run - this way you can define some variables you would use later.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much! I was unable to use include MODULE_NAME though, so I googled it and found out that: Chef::Recipe.send(:include, MODULE_NAME) does the magic.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I've forgot to mention this command also :) I'm happy I could help you!