# Why chef does not execute recipe line by line?

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

Problem is that chef tries to install template first, and only then installs packages. If i comment template block, chef will install sphinxsearch package fine.

But if template block is not commented, sphinxsearch package is not installed, and chef fails with error

> resource template[/etc/sphinxsearch/sphinx.conf] is configured to notify resource service[sphinxsearch] with action reload, but service[sphinxsearch] cannot be found in the resource collection`

Why this happens?

```
##
# Install system packages
##
node['website']['packages'].each do |pkg|
    log 'Installing ' + pkg
    package pkg
end

##
# Configure sphinx
##
template "/etc/sphinxsearch/sphinx.conf" do
    source 'sphinx.erb'
    owner 'root'
    group 'root'
    mode 00644
    notifies :reload, 'service[sphinxsearch]', :delayed
end
```

Comment: Have you tried adding the cookbook that defines `service[sphinxsearch]` in the run list _before_ your own cookbook? In doubt, add an `includes_recipe sphinxsearch` (or however the cookbook name is).

Comment: @StephenKing No, i've just used `package "sphinxsearch"` to install package. It is not enough?

Comment: @avasin you're asking chef to notify a `service` resource called sphinxsearch but there's no `service` resource in your recipe. I highly recommend you to read https://learn.chef.io to get over the basics of chef

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`notifies` and `subscribes` in chef are both trying to reach out to resources that have been defined in your chef run.  They will then call teh indicated action on those resources.  In your case:

`notifies :reload, 'service[sphinxsearch]', :delayed`

is looking for a resource of type `service` named `sphinxsearch` and call the `reload` action on it.  If, at the end of the resource gathering (compile) phase, chef cannot find a `service[sphinxsearch]` resource, then it throws the error.  You don't see the package installed because chef never enters the execution phase.  (See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25980820/please-explain-compile-time-vs-run-time-in-chef-recipes/26000270#26000270) for more on the two phase nature of chef)

As indicated by @IsabelHM, you could solve the problem by adding

```
service 'sphinxsearch' do
  action [:enable, :start]
end
```

I suggest you use `[:enable, :start]` rather than `:nothing` as this will ensure that the service is always running, even if your template doesn't change.  Also, please note that the `service` resource does *not* add a service config for you.  So if the sphinxsearch package does not add a service config, you'll also need a `cookbook_file`, `template`, or `remote_file` resource to create the service config with.

Comment: Thank you very much for such detailed response.

Comment: Excellent, helpful answer

Answer (score 1):

Add this in your recipe.

```
service 'sphinxsearch' do
  action :nothing
end
```