# Command execution in functions in chef-solo

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe, chef-solo

I wrote a simple chef script. There is a folder t1 in /DirectoryPath. Now I'm creating a new folder in /DirectoryPath/t5. But listDirectory() method gives same output, as if no new directory was created. I'm on MAC with chef 11.4

My script is like below

***recipe.rb***

```
def listDirectory() 
  ls = `ls ~/Delete`
  return ls
end

log(listDirectory())

directory '/DirectoryPath/t5' do
  action :create
end

log(listDirectory())
```

***Output***

```
Recipe: test::default
  * log[t1] action write[2015-11-03T15:02:47-08:00] INFO: Processing log[t1] action write
[2015-11-03T15:02:47-08:00] INFO: t1

  * directory[/DirectoryPath/t5] action create[2015-11-03T15:02:47-08:00] INFO: Processing directory[/DirectoryPath/t5] action create (test::default line 10)
[2015-11-03T15:02:47-08:00] INFO: directory[/DirectoryPath/t5] created directory /DirectoryPath/t5

    - create new directory /DirectoryPath/t5
  * log[t1] action write[2015-11-03T15:02:47-08:00] INFO: Processing log[t1] action write
[2015-11-03T15:02:47-08:00] INFO: t1
```

According to me 2nd log statement should show folders t1 and t5, but it is showing only t1. Can I know what could be the reason behind the command returning same result even if there was some change. And how do I avoid it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because of the [two phases of a chef-client run](https://docs.chef.io/chef_client.html#the-chef-client-title-run).

Your calls are executed during *compile phase*, before the `directory` resource is executed (in the *execution phase*).

You should get yourself familiar with the other chef idioms, like [libraries](https://docs.chef.io/libraries.html) and [definitions](https://docs.chef.io/definitions.html). You should not embed ruby code directly in the recipes.

I further suggest to post a new question with the problem that you want to achieve. Pretty sure there is a chef-style way to solve it.

Comment: If I may add a link to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25980820/please-explain-compile-time-vs-run-time-in-chef-recipes), Tejay did a nice explanation of the two pahse run.